# How to scrape all App Store apps on a Google Play Search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use `find_all()` but seem to be having issues finding the tags for the specific information.

I would love to build a wrapper so I can extract data from the app store such as title, publisher, etc (public HTML info).

The code isn't correct, I am aware. The closest thing I could find to a `div` identifier is `"c4"`.

Any insight helps.

```py
# Imports
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Data Defining
url = "https://play.google.com/store/search?q=weather%20app"

# Getting HTML

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
soup.get_text()

results = soup.find_all(id="c4")
```

I am expecting an output of different weather apps and information:

```
Weather App 1
Develop Company 1

Google Weather App
Develop Company 2

Bing Weather App
Bing Developers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting following output from the url

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://play.google.com/store/search?q=weather%20app'
req=requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

cards= soup.find_all("div",class_="vU6FJ p63iDd")

for card in cards:
    app_name= card.find("div",class_="WsMG1c nnK0zc").text
    company = card.find("div",class_="KoLSrc").text
    print("Name: " + app_name)
    print("Company: " + company)
```

Output:

```
Name: Weather app
Company: Accurate Weather Forecast & Weather Radar Map  
Name: AccuWeather: Weather Radar
Company: AccuWeather
Name: Weather Forecast - Accurate Local Weather & Widget
Company: Weather Forecast & Widget & Radar
Name: 1Weather Forecasts & Radar
Company: OneLouder Apps
Name: MyRadar Weather Radar
Company: ACME AtronOmatic LLC
Name: Weather data & microclimate : Weather Underground
Company: Weather Underground
Name: Weather & Widget - Weawow
Company: weawow weather app
Name: Weather forecast
Company: smart-pro android apps
Name: The Secret World of Weather: How to Read Signs in Every Cloud, Breeze, Hill, Street, Plant, Animal, and Dewdrop
Company: Tristan Gooley
Name: The Weather Machine: A Journey Inside the Forecast
Company: Andrew Blum
Name: The Mobile Mind Shift: Engineer Your Business to Win in the Mobile Moment
Company: Julie Ask
Name: Together: The Healing Power of Human Connection in a Sometimes Lonely World
Company: Vivek H. Murthy
Name: The Meadow
Company: James Galvin
Name: The Ancient Egyptian Culture Revealed, 2nd edition
Company: Moustafa Gadalla
Name: The Ancient Egyptian Culture Revealed, 2nd edition
Company: Moustafa Gadalla
Name: Chaos Theory
Company: Introbooks Team
Name: Survival Training: Killer Tips for Toughness and Secret Smart Survival Skills       
Company: Wesley Jones
Name: Kiasunomics 2: Economic Insights for Everyday Life
Company: Ang Swee Hoon
Name: Summary of We Are The Weather by Jonathan Safran Foer
Company: QuickRead
Name: Learn Swift by Building Applications: Explore Swift programming through iOS app development
Company: Emil Atanasov
Name: Weather Hazard Warning Application in Car-to-X Communication: Concepts, Implementations, and Evaluations
Company: Attila Jaeger
Name: Mobile App Development with Ionic, Revised Edition: Cross-Platform Apps with Ionic, 
Angular, and Cordova
Company: Chris Griffith
Name: Good Application Makes a Good Roof Better: A Simplified Guide: Installing Laminated 
Asphalt Shingles for Maximum Life & Weather Protection
Company: ARMA Asphalt Roofing Manufacturers Association
Name: The Secret World of Weather: How to Read Signs in Every Cloud, Breeze, Hill, Street, Plant, Animal, and Dewdrop
Company: Tristan Gooley
Name: The Weather Machine: A Journey Inside the Forecast
Company: Andrew Blum
Name: Space Physics and Aeronomy, Space Weather Effects and Applications
Company: Book 5
Name: How to Build Android Apps with Kotlin: A hands-on guide to developing, testing, and 
publishing your first apps with Android
Company: Alex Forrester
Name: Android 6 for Programmers: An App-Driven Approach, Edition 3
Company: Paul J. Deitel
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** *Working on the basis of extremely dynamically generated identifiers such as class names is only partially reliable.*

The strategy should therefore be based on much more constant identifiers such as `tags` and their structures or, in some cases, `ids`:

```
for e in soup.select('a[href^="/store/apps/details?id"]:has(div[title])'):
    data.append({
        'title': e.select_one('div[title]').get('title'),
        'company':e.find_next('a').text,
        'url':'https://play.google.com'+e.get('href')
    })
```

##### Example

Also **be aware** a real app search should reference to https://play.google.com/store/search?q=weather&c=apps and to get all these apps you have to deal with dynamic rendered / loaded content and scrolling - Thats why this example bases on `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/search?q=weather&c=apps'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight")
    e =  wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="https://policies.google.com/privacy"]')))[-1]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",e)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    if last_height == driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight"):
        break
    else:
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

data = []

for e in soup.select('a[href^="/store/apps/details?id"]:has(div[title])'):
    data.append({
        'title': e.select_one('div[title]').get('title'),
        'company':e.find_next('a').text,
        'url':'https://play.google.com'+e.get('href')
    })

print(pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('app.csv', index=False)
```

##### Output

| title | company | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Weather app | Accurate Weather Forecast & Weather Radar Map | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weather.forecast.weatherchannel |
| The Weather Channel - Radar | The Weather Channel | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weather.Weather |
| AccuWeather: Weather Radar | AccuWeather | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accuweather.android |
| Weather by WeatherBug | WeatherBug | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aws.android |
| Weather Forecast - Accurate Local Weather & Widget | Weather Forecast & Widget & Radar | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accurate.weather.forecast.live |
| The Weather Channel | Weather Group, LLC | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weathergroup.twc |
| WeatherNation | WeatherNation TV, Inc. | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weathernationtv |
| 1Weather Forecasts & Radar | OneLouder Apps | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.expressweather |
| Weather data & microclimate : Weather Underground | Weather Underground | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wunderground.android.weather |
| Weather & Widget - Weawow | weawow weather app | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weawow |
| Weather forecast | smart-pro android apps | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.graph.weather.forecast.channel |

...